# ThreadPool works unpredictable

Tags: java, concurrency, threadpool

I have simple task: 
There is list of arrays and I need to find numbers that divide by 10 in all of them using threadpool.

Here is my code

import java.util.List;

Runnable implementation:

```
public class MyRunnable implements Runnable {
    private List<Integer> numbers;
    private int[] arrayToFind;

    public MyRunnable(List<Integer> numbers, int[] arrayToFind) {
        this.numbers = numbers;
        this.arrayToFind = arrayToFind;
    }

    private boolean isNumber(int n) {
        return n % 10 == 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        for (int i = 0; i < arrayToFind.length; i++) {
            if (isNumber(arrayToFind[i]))
                numbers.add(arrayToFind[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Main class:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String... args) throws InterruptedException{
        int[] arr1 = new int[] {10};
        int[] arr2 = new int[] {400};
        int[] arr3 = new int[] {20};
        int[] arr4 = new int[] {40};
        List<int[]> list = new ArrayList<int[]>();
        list.add(arr1);
        list.add(arr2);
        list.add(arr3);
        list.add(arr4);

        List<Integer> result = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(3);
        for (int[] array : list) {
            executorService.execute(new MyRunnable(result, array));
        }
        executorService.shutdown();

        System.out.println(result);
    }
}
```

The problem is that output sometimes is correct as it should be {10, 20, 40, 400} but sometimes it is {}, sometimes it is {40, 20} etc..

How could you explain this?

Comment: Concurrency is not deterministic.  But to the point of you losing values...you may have a bug on your hands.

Comment: You have no synchronisation around the ArrayList access.

Answer (score 2):

Insertions into a list by default [are not synchronized](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html), thus not thread safe.  If you want to achieve thread safety (so you don't lose data), then wrap your instance inside of `Collections.synchronizedList`.

```
List<Integer> result = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<Integer>());
```

Now your results will all appear (still in nondeterministic order, of course).

Comment: Funny; when I ran it with my smoke tests, it seemed to work fine.  Could you elaborate as to *why* it didn't help?  What did you see?  What happened when you attempted it?

Answer (score 1):

In the API for ExecutorService.shutdown, it says: "This method does not wait for previously submitted tasks to complete execution. Use awaitTermination to do that."

Try using awaitTermination. I bet that will fix your problem

Comment: How exactly should I use this method? It requires 2 parameters, what should I pass to it?

Comment: You should read the API for this and decide what your appropriate wait time should be

Answer (score 0):

It seems that sometimes ExecutorService shutdowns until some or your MyRunnable.run are finished. Generally speaking, ExecutorService.execute+Runnable allow you to do "some work" in parallel when you aren't interested in the result. If you need to wait until all results are calculated, use ExecutorService.invokeAll+Callable. See for example:

http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-util-concurrent/executorservice.html

And, finally, store the result of calculation in a thread safe collection:

```
public static class MyCallable implements Callable<Boolean> {
    private Set<Integer> numbers;
    private int[] arrayToFind;

    public MyCallable(Set<Integer> numbers, int[] arrayToFind) {
        this.numbers = numbers;
        this.arrayToFind = arrayToFind;
    }

    private boolean isNumber(int n) {
        return n % 10 == 0;
    }

    @Override
    public Boolean call() {
        for (int i = 0; i < arrayToFind.length; i++) {
            if (isNumber(arrayToFind[i]))
                numbers.add(arrayToFind[i]);
        }
        return true;
    }
}


public static void main(String... args) throws InterruptedException{
    int[] arr1 = new int[] {10};
    int[] arr2 = new int[] {400};
    int[] arr3 = new int[] {20};
    int[] arr4 = new int[] {40};
    List<int[]> list = new ArrayList<>();
    list.add(arr1);
    list.add(arr2);
    list.add(arr3);
    list.add(arr4);

    Set<Integer> result = Collections.newSetFromMap(new ConcurrentHashMap<Integer, Boolean>());
    List<MyCallable> myCallables = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int[] array : list) {
        myCallables.add(new MyCallable(result, array));
    }
    ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(3);
    executorService.invokeAll(myCallables);
    executorService.shutdown();
    System.out.println(result);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not waiting for the tasks to complete, before printing out the result. That's why the inconsistency. Instead of execute, use submit method to submit tasks to executor as it returns you a Future instance, which can be used to wait for the task to complete.

Checkout the [Future's](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html) javadoc

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException {
    int[] arr1 = new int[] { 10 };
    int[] arr2 = new int[] { 400 };
    int[] arr3 = new int[] { 20 };
    int[] arr4 = new int[] { 40 };
    List<int[]> list = new ArrayList<int[]>();
    list.add(arr1);
    list.add(arr2);
    list.add(arr3);
    list.add(arr4);

    List<Integer> result = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    List<Future<?>> futures = new ArrayList<Future<?>>();
    ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(3);
    for (int[] array : list) {
        futures.add(executorService.submit(new MyRunnable(result, array)));
    }
    executorService.shutdown();

    for (Future<?> future : futures) {
        future.get();
    }

    System.out.println(result);
}
```